# Can theism be reconciled with the apparent state of dualism?

Tags: philosophy-of-religion, dualism

The [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/afterlife) states that "dualism has come upon hard times lately, and is widely regarded as being discredited."

It seems to me that most theists (I'm thinking mostly of Christians here) accept dualism to be true. If they do not, there seems to be many issues regarding how exactly one is "moved" into heaven, or how one's consciousness can persist after the death of a material body.

However, many prominent philosophers still accept theism in one way or another. How, then, can these philosophers accept a "discredited" view? Do they instead accept a materialist account of the afterlife with all of its difficulties?

Comment: Can you provide detail about how it's discredited?

Comment: @DonBranson I'm just quoting the SEP when saying that it is discredited, but it seems to me that modern advancements in medicine have mostly shown a deep and inseparable connection between the body and the mind, such as how easily the mind can be changed through physical means (such as drugs or brain tumors). Also, many of the arguments against dualism, such as the problem of interaction and the problem of how to explain what would define an immaterial mind.

Comment: I think the bigger problem is the claim that most Christians are committed to dualism. Catholics are not ... because Aquinas is a hylomorphist.

Comment: @virmaior How, then, is that reconciled with the difficulty of explaining a materialist idea of the afterlife? For example, how is the sense of individuality "preserved" or "moved" into heavenly existence for us, if our bodies to not "come with us"?

Comment: Aquinas did struggle with this. He ended up defending the idea of soul as "substantial form" that is still tied to its matter (body), but yet has independent causal powers of its own that allow it to "subsist" past disembodiment, albeit no longer as a fully human soul. This is a step in the direction of dualism, but it stops just short of it, see [What would happen to the soul as the form of the body under massive changes to the body?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/46756/9148)

Comment: @Conifold When you say that "disembodiment" occurs, don't most Christians (at least some) say that the soul is "re-embodied" in heaven, as a full human soul?

Comment: That is not what Aquinas says, *human* soul is attached to human body as its form. The "substantial form" that does persist is not human, strictly speaking, and I do not think that what happens in heaven (or hell) is re-embodiment exactly. But loose popular beliefs that suffice for the laymen and subtle parsing of theologians are two different things. Just as popular talk about the Big Bang or Theory of Everything are very different from what theoretical physicists actually say.

Comment: @Conifold It seems fairly undesirable to exist as a form that is not even "human," so I'm assuming that there are theistic alternatives to this, as there are many philosophers who believe that re-embodiment occurs in heaven, continuing to exist as a fully human person.

Comment: Thomism is the official theology of Catholicism. Something like re-embodiment is only supposed to happen after the final days, not immediately, as the bodies are recreated in the Kingdom Come. The issue is controversial, the sense of  preservation of personal identity under such recreation is a big problem, see various materialist and immaterialist accounts under [IEP Resurrection](https://www.iep.utm.edu/resurrec/) , and  [Teilhard de Chardin's version](http://rationalcatholic.blogspot.com/2016/04/last-days-and-resurrection-dead-iii.html), for example.

Comment: @Josh I'm not if you're trying to argue or just asking because you don't know much about what Christians and Catholics believe. (1) What is the `materialist idea of the afterlife`? and why is anyone committed to it? (2) on the catholic view, humans cannot normally exist without bodies and in fact have bodies in the next life. There's thousands of pages of academic work on this topic in medieval philosophy. It's not my area of expertise but the idea is that a human soul is the organizing principle of a human and that new matter can still be organized by the same soul ...

Comment: @virmaior 1) When I say materialist idea of the afterlife, I mean that we are resurrected in a body, without assuming the presence of another substance that constitutes a person. As you say, I think Catholics would be committed to this.

Comment: You might be using words causally, but the sentence:  `I mean that we are resurrected in a body, without assuming the presence of another substance that constitutes a person` is odd. On the Catholic view, substance = form + matter. That's the entire point. So for Catholics, commitment to the resurrection is the same as commitment to the view that God will take the souls of people and make it so they organize matter humanly as a single substance.

Comment: @Conifold, Whether HUMANS are fully "human" without bodies, is not really the issue for THEISM.  Catholicism cannot really be considered anything other than a dualist worldview.  God pre-existed matter.  All theists are either dualists or idealists.

Comment: @Dcleve I think you're using dualism with respect to the existence of something other than matter, but I had taken the question to be using dualism with respect to believing mind and brain are distinct (there's *lots* of different uses of the term dualism).

Comment: @virmaior -- No, I am considering the question as larger than just us humans.  Theism presupposes a non-physical agency, which makes mind distinct from matter.

Comment: Shouldn't theists themselves decide what is the issue for them? Thomists do not consider their hylomorphism to be either substance dualism or idealism, but then the terms are often used pretty loosely in popular talk. There are even materialist interpretations, as you can see in IEP.

Comment: Actually the conflict of a non-material monism philosophy and a material dualism has been a subject of debate in Hinduism (vedanta) for thousands of years. Most modern day Hindus (vedantists) are dualists. In Vedanta, the individual consists of 'sheaths' and the material sheath decays on death (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/where-does-a-soul-attach-to-the-body/6787#6787). The fine sheaths survive. All dualistic philosophies which have an extra-cosmic creator God outside of the creation wrestle with this quandry.

Comment: It is the thrust of the old question from the middle ages - how many angels can dance on the head of a pin? (if they're non-material beings, an infinite number can, if material beings, than only one can).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the actual beliefs of philosophers are more open to dualism than the "discredited" quote implies.  The philosophical survey shows a majority of philosophers to be physicalists (56.5%), but with 27.1% non-physicalist, and 16.4% other -- there is certainly a lot of room for dualism and idealism among contemporary philosophy.  http://consc.net/papers/survey.pdf  As the question notes, theism generally presupposes dualism, and with 14.6% theists among philosophers (and another 12.6% other, which pretty much also requires dualism or idealism) the dualists among philosophers are plausibly between 15-25%.

Note the SEP entry on dualism itself is not nearly as dismissive as that sentence fragment -- here is a key quote:

> although dualism has been out of fashion in psychology since the advent of behaviourism (Watson 1913) and in philosophy since Ryle (1949), the argument is by no means over. Some distinguished neurologists, such as Sherrington (1940) and Eccles (Popper and Eccles 1977) have continued to defend dualism as the only theory that can preserve the data of consciousness. Amongst mainstream philosophers, discontent with physicalism led to a modest revival of property dualism in the last decade of the twentieth century.

Note "out of fashion" is a far cry from "discredited".  https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dualism/

A good discussion about that fashion is in Papineau's The Rise of Physicalism:  https://www.academia.edu/819823/The_Rise_of_Physicalism  Papineau traces the decline of dualism to the success of biochemistry, and the simultaneous failures of vitalism in biology, plus the successful reduction of much of chemistry and physics to fundamental physics forces and particles.  Physicalism would therefore be a "progressive" Lakatian Research Programme:  http://people.loyno.edu/~folse/Lakatos.html

However, the failure of reductionism in general, and in particular the failure of reductionist philosophy of mind, has begun to reverse that fashion. https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-reduction/ Physicalism is becoming a "regressive" program, and dualism is under increasing reconsideration.

Since the end of the 20th century, the credibility of dualism has continued to grow.

Even Jaegwon Kim is now a dualist:  [https://www.amazon.com/Physicalism-Something-Princeton-Monographs-Philosophy-ebook/dp/B005646D3I](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005646D3I)

Here are four more references that show the increasing vigor of dualist thought:

[https://www.amazon.com/Soul-How-Know-Real-Matters/dp/0802411002/ref=pd_sbs_14_2/141-2257182-8610804?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=0802411002&pd_rd_r=ad786f70-a2cc-11e9-a041-afcf3c2cca71&pd_rd_w=CxVCe&pd_rd_wg=ZTnlj&pf_rd_p=588939de-d3f8-42f1-a3d8-d556eae5797d&pf_rd_r=NY4HB7Y1KNTN2FG0VK66&psc=1&refRID=NY4HB7Y1KNTN2FG0VK66](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0802411002)

[https://www.amazon.com/Mind-Brain-Free-Richard-Swinburne/dp/0199662576/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=swinburne+free+will&qid=1562733645&s=books&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0199662576)

[https://www.amazon.com/Soul-Hypothesis-Investigations-into-Existence/dp/1441152245/ref=pd_sbs_14_1/141-2257182-8610804?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=1441152245&pd_rd_r=ad786f70-a2cc-11e9-a041-afcf3c2cca71&pd_rd_w=CxVCe&pd_rd_wg=ZTnlj&pf_rd_p=588939de-d3f8-42f1-a3d8-d556eae5797d&pf_rd_r=NY4HB7Y1KNTN2FG0VK66&psc=1&refRID=NY4HB7Y1KNTN2FG0VK66](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1441152245)

[https://www.amazon.com/Brief-History-Soul-Stewart-Goetz/dp/1405196335/ref=sr_1_69?keywords=soul+science+philosophy&qid=1562733508&s=books&sr=1-69](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1405196335)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I accepted it. I'm wondering: are the questions regarding dualism/materialism questions of logical coherence, or questions of what is best supported by the evidence? Are both materialism and dualism considered logically coherent explanations of the world?

Comment: Are you including under "dualism" views which say consciousness is purely epiphenomenal, so that the physical world is causally closed and all human *behavior* has a purely physical explanation? I know Chalmers (who co-authored that first survey you linked) has a view like this, not sure about Jaegwon Kim...in any case it seems to me this would pose many of the same problems for theistic ideas like a God who holds us morally responsible for our actions, or even the broad idea that there can be such a thing as an intelligence that does *not* have the same relation to physical computations.

Comment: @Hypnosifl  Kim is an only partial dualist relative to consciousness -- he considers SOME of consciousness to be reducible to matter, but some aspects of qualia are immaterial.  The immaterial experience of qualia he considers to be epiphenomenal -- but as we can talk about and describe these qualia -- this is a nonsense position.  That a thinker of Kim's stature was forced to concede it -- is an indication of the severity of the problems with materialism.  Chalmers is also an epiphenomenalist relative to mind.  Chalmers holds by epiphenomenal pan-psychism, which can't support a God.

Comment: So they are not theists, they are non-theist dualists.

Comment: A worldview which can support a God, and the specific God of the Abrahamic religions, is a smaller subset of dualism.  I treat philosophy and metaphysics as a form of scientific exploration.  IS dualism true?  Or materialism, or Idealism?  and if so, which version?  Look for the test cases, and build up an evidenced case.  I think this is how philosophy SHOULD be done -- rather than assuming "Abrahamic God exists, and the universe is such that it agrees with Scripture".  My belief is that a dualism close to Abrahamic concepts is the case -- although without the Abrahamic God in it.

Comment: @Josh  Some materialists claim dualism is logically incoherent --  but I don't think such claims are themselves logically coherent!  ;-)  Thomism attempts to prove God with logic - but these proofs fail.  Some atheists attempt to prove God is impossible, but these proofs fail too.  The nature of the world is a contingent question, and logic is not useful to establish it.  Me -- I apply empiricism to metaphysical claims -- spell out the model one is proposing, and collect the support to justify it, and the reasons to reject it, and weigh them -- and compare to each major alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Just so it's said, the phrase 'most theists' is reductionistic, and a bit anti-intellectual. I mean, back in the year zero 'most people' believed that the earth was flat, but we don't take that as the standard for modern physics. We allow that physics can grow and change over time to become something more intellectually sophisticated, and we *give precedence* to more intellectually sophisticated expressions of it. Flat-earthers, for all their exuberance, are treated more or less a joke in the modern world...

Simple dualisms in theology and religious philosophy are unsophisticated constructs. Yes, lots of people cling to them (because lots of people are driven by fear rather than reason), but asserting this as the epitome of religious thought (not an unfortunate decompensation of it) is prejudicial at best.

Comment: "back in the year zero 'most people' believed that the earth was flat," Do you have supporting docs for this claim?

Comment: Please don't insult the intelligence of everyone here. The pertinent claim in my post is that physics has advanced over the last few millennia. If you do not believe that to be the case, say so and we'll discuss the matter. Otherwise questions like this are pure rhetoric that do not advance the discussion in any way.