# Can any philosophy of mind be empirically verified?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mind, materialism, dualism

(This is sort of a follow-up from [this](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/64456/can-theism-be-reconciled-with-the-apparent-state-of-dualism) question)

Can dualism, materialism, or anything in between be empirically verified? There seems to be some disagreement here. [This](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/neuroscience/mind-body-problem) page presents both views nicely. Tryon, from this page, says that "The mind–body problem is actually a mistake based in ignorance." He argues that because of advances in neuroscience, reductive physicalism is the only way to go.

Sarıhan, on the same page, says that "No matter what detailed and direct mapping we establish between mental and neural states, there are so many options that remain on the table before we can proclaim that we have reduced mental processes to brain processes."

Given that no empirical evidence will truly *disprove* either side, it is a matter of probability. But can that even be applied here? Why, initially, assume that there is a 50/50 chance of either dualism or not (which, it seems, is needed for evidence to "tilt" the scale on way or another. If the prior probabilities are too different, evidence won't have any weight)? Why do we assume that our somewhat arbitrarily defined distinctions between dualism and materialism have any reflection on reality? It seems that you can draw this line wherever you want, and assign a "50/50" probability to it. Therefore, it seems that assigning any sort of probabilities is not correct. This would make the argument essentially immune to any sort of empirical work, would it not?

So, my question is, which view is more "correct," (either Tryon's or Sarıhan's) from a philosophical perspective?

Comment: Tryon is channeling his personal wishful thinking, Sarihan is right (and full reduction is very likely intractable in principle), and you are half right. It is true that probabilities are nonsensical here, it is not true that "this would make the argument essentially immune to any sort of empirical work". If neuroscientists manage to extract/induce/predict subjectively reported thoughts from/by patterns of neuronal firing, neurophysicalism will become overwhelmingly plausible, and no philosophical "it could still be else" would help much. But it is a big "if".

Comment: @Conifold Why would that make neurophysicalism overwhelmingly plausible? If there is still a possibility for something else, as Sarihan says, "The first obstacle is that correlation does not mean identity." If subjective thoughts were to be correlated with neuronal firing, how would that prove causation? Also, if there is a *possibility* for something else, we would not know the probability of that something else, even if it wasn't required for our theory, no?

Comment: Because academic musings like "correlation does not mean identity" and "there is a possibility for something else" mean very little in the face of a successful research program. *All* empirical identities are inferred from correlations, they just have to be persistent enough, and alternatives are abandoned not because they are disproved (which is impossible), but because they are discredited by the success. This is why we no longer have ether or creationism, even though "there is a possibility" and correlation between a theory and observations may not be caused by the theory being true.

Comment: Correlation _refutes_ identity, because it is a relation b/w two things which must be kept clear of each other to establish an association between them. As long as they are kept separate, correlation can groove deeper and thinner, only to preserve them away from merging into identity. Scientists exploit this endlessly to have research money: they wish to support the gap between mind and neurons, saying in hypocrisy (or in self-deceit?) they want to identify the two sides. Identities finally proclaimed as "found" or "proved" in place of correlations are the leaps of fatigue-and-quit.

Comment: @Conifold I see. So it is purely a pragmatic decision?

Comment: @Josh Not "purely", and not all pragmatic, but plausibility is not all about "empirical verification" either. It helps to make successful predictions, but *also* to explain things without too much twisting, fit well into a working general picture, etc., see [epistemic values](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-objectivity/). Even pragmatic success itself is a diffused form of "verification". And given [underdetermination of theory by observations](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-underdetermination/) the only alternative is permanent indecision about everything.

Comment: @Conifold As I see it, none of these things can be given a rigorous proof of validity. For example, fitting well into a working general picture. Besides aesthetic value, I don't see how you can justify this (at least not from a statistical perspective). I remember watching this Oxford (I think) lecture where the lecturer stated that science has **no** rational basis, yet it still should be used because it aligns with the way we must think as humans. Do you agree with this?

Comment: My answer here is "none of the above".  The answer is complex, and documenting it will be a mess, so I will start with a summary here.  1) to start with, verification is the wrong term.  Science does falsification, and builds up confidence if enough falsification tests are passed.  2) Tryon is "right" that we can do empirical tests, but wrong about his even doing them.  He is just redoing variants of dropping a brick vs a feather, stone vs a paper, lead ball vs an inflated balloon, etc.  He is just doing confirmation bias. Mind is clearly STRONGLY INFLUENCED by brain.

Comment: But the testing he cites is not falsification testing.  He needs to look at limit cases and showing that reduction works in all cases.  IFF every time we had thought X, then neurons Y were firing, and every time neurons Y were firing , we had thought X, then identity/reduction would be a reasonable conclusion.  BUT -- that is not what the tests show.  First we have multiple realizability.  We have a thought, and neuros Y fire.  Then we have the same thought, and somewhat different neurons, Y1 fire.  Then next time it is Y2, etc.  And sometimes it is Z.  Lots of different neurons can support X.

Comment: This isn't identity!  Then test the other way.  Lots of times Y fires, we DO NOT think X.  Identity claims are refuted.  Worse -- one of the main features of mind is INTEGRATION.  We hear, feel and smell separately, but integrate them into a combined understanding we just slipped in a dog pile.  BUT -- the neurology does not seem to have an identifiable integration module -- where in the brain fires when integrating like this -- is unpredictable.  Basically, Tryon is just ASSUMING reduction, and has definitely not CONFIRMED it. And science has abandoned reductionism, due to similar failures.

Comment: But Sarihan is wrong too.  We CAN test these models, and reject one or another.  The best book I have found on Philosophy of Mind is by Susan Blackmore, and it is chock full of tests of theories of mind.  Here is my review:  https://www.amazon.com/Consciousness-Short-Introduction-Susan-Blackmore/dp/0192805851?ref=pf_vv_at_pdctrvw_dp  Blackmore thinks materialism is refuted by these test cases.  BUT -- she is a dogmatic materialist, so she rejects the EVIDENCE (IE rejects the experience of consciousness, and so science).

Comment: @Conifold this is my informed opinion, which would I think be useful, but without links is it good form for an answer?  Could/should I make these posts an answer?

Comment: Nothing at all can be given "rigorous proof of validity". To give a proof, even in mathematics, one needs to accept premises and rules on faith, and then trust that they are capable of following those rules. Not even all of that would help to "rigorously prove" that the Sun will rise tomorrow. Therefore, the "truly disprove"/"rigorous proof" standard is itself a naive fantasy with little rational basis, something aspirational for beginners. Rationality is a much more complex and subtle matter than either "rigor" or your Oxford lecturer's platitude suggest.

Comment: @Dcleve I think the OP is using "verification" so generically that differences with falsification, confirmation or "testing" do not even matter. You could convert your comments into an answer, but it would help if you reproduce references Tryon cites, before giving your analysis, and give your own sources of information on neurology, multiple realizability, and reductionism, along with your assessment.

Comment: @Conifold Thank you, that makes sense.

Comment: Sarıhan has a weak argument for dualism, an argument that can leave you unsure about anything in reality. For example, how do we know that immunotherapy directly helps eliminate cancer instead of solicitating some supernatural entity indirectly. How do we know that cataracts can be a hereditary trait when it's possible for a family to be possessed by an ocular demon. How do we know that methanol is toxic when all deaths can be coincidental. It takes some bias in accepting evidence to accept things like modern medicine etc., but dismiss neuroscience because something else "could" be possible.

Answer (score 1):

The issues hangs on what we mean by 'empirical'. You say,

*Given that no empirical evidence will truly disprove either side, it is a matter of probability.*

Here you are assuming that 'empirical' means 'sensory'. This accords with most dictionary definitions and is not a problem. But consciousness is not an empirical phenomenon and yet we know we are conscious. Thus knowledge is not necessarily empirical and the ability of empiricism to prove or disprove 'either side' is not a problem.

A study of consciousness will settle the matter, but it will not be an empirical study. Such a study will, if successful, leave nothing as a matter of probability.

Not all knowledge is derived from the physical senses. Sensory data is never going to tell us much about what is receiving and noting this sensory data. Sensory data is theory-laden and liable to all sorts of errors.

Note that Descartes' 'Cogito' is not sensory data. This is why he considered it reliable.

Theories in philosophy of mind may be tested by a 'hands-on' method known variously as apperception, meditation or self-enquiry. Academic philosophers of mind rarely go in for such activities so must rely on sensory data. Accordingly, they usually deny the possibility of testing their theories. But this is a very inneffective way to study mind and consciousness and not at all scientific. Those who study consciousness and mind in a scientific manner, by doing the field-work, do not leave things to conjecture and the balance of probabilities but test their theories in experience.

Comment: So you're saying that it's possible to derive the basis of consciousness just through the experience of being conscious? Otherwise, I think you would have to rely on empirical information.

Comment: Neat! "Empirical ≠ Sensory" And yet that fact is neither empirical nor sensory 

Comment: @Josh - I don't know what you mean by 'derive the basis of consciousness', or how empirical information would tell us anything about it when it cannot even establish its existence. Do you remember Behaviourism? .   . .

Comment: @Josh Just noticed I didn't answer your question. It is possible to know the basis of consciousness, but not to derive it. A derived result is never certain knowledge.