# Are you a 'body' according to Thomas Aquinas?

Tags: aquinas

Usually we say that we 'have' a body than that we 'are' a body. Essentially we are human beings but is it wrong to deny that we are bodies according to Thomas?

Comment: Some references ?

Comment: Maybe "is" must be intended in terms of *essence*: what is the essence of human beings ?

Comment: Yes, it is wrong. According to the Aristotelian hylomorphism that Aquinas followed, any thing is a fusion of matter and form. It is wrong to say that it is either on its own. Our body is the matter, and our soul is the form. It is particularly wrong with the body because, unlike the soul, it does not even subsist on its own.

Comment: you say 'Yes, it is wrong'. But that means that 'we are a body' is correct? Probably you meant 'no it is not wrong because we are humans 'made of' body'?

Comment: There is nothing contradictory in saying that we both have and are a body. Indeed, there are phenomenologists and anthropologists building their whole philosophies on the point that humans both have and are their body.

Comment: Related [What would happen to the soul as the form of the body, according to scholastics, under massive changes to the body?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/46756/9148)

Comment: I've voted to reopen. The question is very clear.

Answer (score 1):

According to the well-known Aristotelian definition, humans are "rational animals", i.e. animals (with body) with intellectual faculties.

See [Aquinas: Body and Soul](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aquinas/#BodSou):

> Considered as a substantial form of a material body, the soul exists in a living being as the substantial form of an animal.

Humans are *substances*, made of matter and form. The living being **is** the human.

There is no "modern" *self* that "owns the body".

Comment: Do you think that nobody in those days ever had said or discussed about the line 'I have or am a body'?